# Sql syntax error in Android 10, work fine in other versions

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Here is the Error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: 
SELECT _id, bucket_display_name, bucket_id, _id, orientation 
FROM images 
WHERE ((is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' ))) AND ((1) GROUP BY 1,(2)) 
ORDER BY date_modified DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using group by method inside WHERE closure bracket. Remove it outside of the bracket.

**Fixed query:**

```
SELECT
  _id,
  bucket_display_name,
  bucket_id,
  _id,
  orientation
FROM
  images
WHERE
  (
    (is_pending = 0)
    AND (is_trashed = 0)
    AND (volume_name IN ('external_primary'))
  )
  AND ((1))
GROUP BY
  1,(2)
ORDER BY
  date_modified DESC
```